# Sample/Dummy Data Generation in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, sample-data, dummy-data

Is there a standard gem for creating data for testing purposes for Rails 3?

I am interested in using [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) or [Forgery](https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery) but is there a better approach?

What is the best way to generate and use sample data?

Comment: You can generate the data by this gem or by a sequence, all is good

Answer (score 1):

The two I'd recommend using would be [factory_girl_rails](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) by [Thoughtbot](http://thoughtbot.com/) and [faker](http://github.com/stympy/faker). These are by far the best two for generating sample data.

Comment: Do you use these together? FactoryGirl looks like a lot of work.